# Create a list with variable names in it

Tags: python

I think this question has been asked many times, but I can't find the answer. I am probably not using the correct words in my searches.

I am a beginner in python and I am learning to make simple games, with the pygame library. I would like to create a variable `character`, containing x and y coordinates.
I would like something like `character[x=default_value,y=default_value]`, and then edit these coordinates for example by typing `character[x]=new_value`.

Is there a way to achieve something like that in python ?

EDIT : Thank you all, I used dictionary like that `character= {'x':'value', 'y':'value'}` and it works perfectly!

Comment: What you describe is a dictionary...

Comment: Or even better, a `defaultdict` (because of the default values)

Comment: Or create a `class`:  `class Character: def __init__(self, x=default_value, y=default_value): self.x = x; self.y = y ...`

Comment: On this site, show your appreciation by upvoting all the useful answers. You do that by clicking the up-arrow at the top-left of the answer. In addition, accept the best answer (if it actually answers your question) by clicking the checkmark near the top-left of the answer. That is better than saying thanks in a comment. It also helps others to see that your question was answered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a dictionary like this:

```
character = {'Name': 'Mary', 'xPos': 0, 'yPos': 0}
character['xPos'] = 10
```

Answer (score 0):

A dict would work, but a [class](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html) is a better fit IMO.

```
class Character:
    def __init__(self, x=0, y=0):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

arthur = Character(9, 9)
arthur.x = 15
```

*Due credit to [AChampion](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2750492/achampion) for posting the class in [a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42838366/create-a-list-with-variable-names-in-it#comment72786589_42838366)*

Answer (score -1):

You can use dictionary.

```
character = dict()
character['x']= default_value
character['y']= default_value
```

You might want to have a look at this [Documentation](https://learnpythonthehardway.org/book/ex39.html)

Comment: Why do you use the `dict` constructor instead of a literal `{}`? And why do you assign the keys later instead of on the same line? It's much simpler to do `character = {'x': default_value, 'y': default_value}` or `character = dict(x=default_value, y=default_value)`

Comment: After looking at the question, I thought what @whin3 was looking for is a dictionary and it's values could be modified over time. Which is what my answer addresses, creating and editing dictionary. As you (@wjandrea) said using literal `{}` is simple, but when I was answering I was looking for solution rather than simple/difficult solution. After all, I didn't feel difference between both has a huge difference in terms of the question and it's answer.